# how to print words excluding particular letter string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write a program to prompt the user to enter a string of forbidden letters and then print the number of words that don’t contain any of them

This is what I have:

```
fin=open("demo.txt",'r')
letters=str(raw_input("Enter the key you want to exclude"))
def avoid ():   
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        for l in letters:
            if l not in word: 
                print word          
avoid()
```

If I use the **in** keyword it prints all the words that have the particular strings. But it's not working the same when I am using **not in**.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
for l in letters:
    if l in word:
        break  # we found the letter in the word, so stop looping
else:
    # This will execute only when the loop above didn't find
    # any of the letters. 
    print(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but still programs is avoids only first letter from the string

Comment: are you sure about that? note that the above code should be inside a `for word in ...` loop, as it only shows the "only print words not containing any of the letters" logic.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to make the letters a set, split each line into words and sum how many times there were words with no forbidden letters:

```
with open("demo.txt", 'r') as f:
    letters = set(raw_input("Enter the key you want to exclude"))
    print(sum(not letters.intersection(w) for line in f for w in line.split()))
```

You could also use [str.translate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm),checking if the word length has changed after translating:

```
with open("demo.txt", 'r') as f:
    letters = raw_input("Enter the key you want to exclude")
    print(sum(len(w.translate(None, letters)) == len(w) for line in f for w in line.split()))
```

If the word is the same length after trying to remove any `letters` then the word does not contain any letter from letters.

Or using `any`:

```
with open("in.txt", 'r') as f:
    letters = raw_input("Enter the key you want to exclude")
    print(sum(not any(let in w for let in letters) for line in f for w in line.split()))
```

`any(let in w for let in letters)` will check every letter in letters and see if any letter is in each word, if it finds a forbidden letter it will short circuit and return `True` or else return `False` if no letter appeared in the word then move on to the next word .

You cannot use `if l in word` unless you only have one word per line, you need to split into individual words.

Using your own code you just need to break when you find a letter in the word, else print the word if we looped over all the letters and found no match:

```
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    for l in letters:
        if l  in word:
            break 
    else:
         print word
```

The pythonic way to do what you want in your loop would be to use any:

```
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    if not any(l not in word for l in letters): 
         print word
```

Which is equivalent to the break/else just a lot nicer.

If you want the sum then you need to keep track as you go:

```
  total = 0
  for line in fin:
      word = line.strip()
      if not any(l not in word  for l in letters): 
           total += 1
 print(total)
```

Which is a less efficient way of doing:

```
print(sum(not any(let in w.rstrip() for let in letters) for word in f))
```

Comment: @def_0101, no worries,  using `any` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way.

```
exclude = set(raw_input("Enter the key you want to exclude"))
with open("demo.txt") as f:
    print len(filter(exclude.isdisjoint, f.read().split()))
```

Comment: You're welcome. Are you still waiting for something, though? (I notice you haven't accepted any of our answers yet).

Answer (score -1):

This is better:

```
    forbidden='ab'
    listofstring=['a','ab','acc','aaabb']
    for i in listofstring:
        if not any((c in i) for c in forbidden):
            print i
```

Comment: This is wrong, you are checking if all the forbidden letters are in the word not any

Comment: @PadraicCunningham """words that don’t contain any of them""" I interpreted from this. I think ' all ' is the way to go. Any suggestions

Comment: if a or b appear in the string then this will print the string. You are checking if all the forbidden letters are in the word not any

Comment: @PadraicCunningham now is it fine?